# How to supply 12V 4 pcs of solenoid water valve

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, relay, solenoid

[enter link description here](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/vivian-w-dc12v-nc-normally-closed-water-solenoid-valve-g12-inch-plastic-electrical-solenoid-valve-for-water-dispenser-i2918494024-s14198695448.html?exlaz=d_1:mm_150050845_51350205_2010350205::12:12305590551!114405067821!!!aud-1949663871797:pla-293946777986!c!293946777986!14198695448!548749368&gclid=Cj0KCQiAg_KbBhDLARIsANx7wAzkjxuD9-8kKEfb2Tp2M5r4juSZygIc9bp_anOl0VdJQW-SxY52KxEaAnvoEALw_wcB)I am trying to control 4pcs of 12V solenoid water valve using Nodemcu and 5V 8-channel relay. The VIN pin and Ground pin of Nodemcu is connected to VCC and Ground pin of the relay. Then the D2 pin of Nodemcu is connected to the IN1 pin of relay. Then I am wiring the common ground of relay to the 12V 2A power supply, and the solenoid water valve is wired to the Normally Closed of relay and the power supply. This is only 1 solenoid valve. The problem is can I provide enough voltage for 4 different solenoid valve using only 1 12V 2A power supply?

Comment: `can I provide enough voltage` ... it's not the voltage that you have to worry about, it is the current ... how much current does one valve require? ... please add a link to the valve datasheet

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic. Click on edit and the schematic symbol. You can draw it there and insert your schematic into your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the linked datasheet, each solenoid valve draws 300mA when energized, which adds up to 1.2A @ 12V. If the remaining 800mA is sufficient for your Nodemcu and your relay board and if your power supply is actually capable of continuous 2A @12V then you are okay.

Since you have the relay N.C. contacts driving the solenoid valves, you probably don't need to count the relay coil consumption since the solenoid will be off when the relay is energized, and usually they'll draw less than the solenoid valve.

If you're deriving all the power from 12V, if you are using more relays, and especially if you're using a power-wasting linear regulator, you may be close to exceeding the maximum.